# In a composited component, how can child access the state property of top most

Tags: reactjs

For simplification, I have a a component, that includes a subcomponent. The top parent component is the only stateful compontent. But the state of this needs to be set on children deep within. How can these children access the state of the top most parent?

Is passing the state down via `props` the only way? I ask because I have a comonent that has many children deep down, so to access state I would have to pass state as a prop to 5 levels, just so 5th level can access state.

For a simplified example:

```
var Timer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {secondsElapsed: 0};
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({secondsElapsed: this.state.secondsElapsed + 1});
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Label />
    );
  }
});

var Label = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

This example gives `this.state is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in general two well accepted ways to do this.

1. Indeed pass the properties down the tree of components. This can sometimes work very well, and is something I personally use a lot for more UI work in the components, like making sure a pagination works generically all over the app (total pages, currentpage, items per page). For more app 'state' kind of things this is generally not the right approach
2. Switch to something to manage your application state, like [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), which will help you with the concept of a store to keep this state in, if both components need this. I use the [alt](http://alt.js.org/) implementation, but [Facebook's official](https://github.com/facebook/flux) and other ones are also very well known.

In general I'd advise you to dive a bit into some videos of React and Flux, perhaps the ones where people show you how they do certain things like this. For example [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5E894TmHJg) one.

Comment: Ah!! Flux looks great. I think it will hehlp me a lot because, I need to produce and maintain multiple components that respect a single state object. Flux is the way to achieve that huh? So this will be 2 birds with 1 stone, it handles the deep down children and also maintain state across cloned components?

Comment: Correct, you could see it almost as some kind of singleton that components can use as a 'prop' so you don't have those massive dependencies everywhere. I don't build any React apps without it anymore!

Comment: Thanks so much janpieter. I was looking at it, but was having some difficulty. Could you please use Flux in a jsfiddle to show one Store, and then that creates three `hello blah`, divs, where blah is the state. I couldn't figure out what was so "Fluxy" about it, I just keep making a global object, and set state to that. I can make another question for that, should i do so?

Comment: @Noitidart I've been trying to get you a nice working JSFiddle for the past 20 minutes but it seems a bit hard compared to just checking out their tutorial. That should show you how it 'should' be done. Location for that is: https://github.com/goatslacker/alt-tutorial.

Ones using Facebook's pure flux can be found here: https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort @janpeter I really appreciate it! I will check out those examples! :) I'll try pure flux first then go advanced to alt :)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the state down to an arbitrary depth by using a slightly experimental feature of react called "contexts".

They have [a page detailing it](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). Head the warning at the top, as this should be used for special circumstances only.

Try to perhaps refactor or think ahead when using contexts, as they can lead your to create subcomponents which assume certain contexts, which limits their reusability.

Comment: This is very interesting! Thank you so much Matt!